# Yii2 using old PHP version

Tags: php, version

I have updated the PHP version to 5.6.18 in my Mac. But my Yii2 application is still using PHP/5.5.14 version. How can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as PHP 5.16.18, but whatever version you used, it's not related to Yii2 itself. If you use MAMP PRO you can easily switch versions, otherwise you need to set proper PHP version that's loaded by yourself.

Comment: @Dexa yes sorry typo, I am not using MAMP PRO and when I run php -v in command line it shows the new version.

Comment: command line version and one loaded by your apache/nginx is not the same. You need to update both.

Comment: Thanks a lot and how can I show to apache to use which version?

Comment: check this out http://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: Thank you so much @Dexa, it helped!